How can I rename my VS Code Server tunnel?
I'm hosting my own VS Code server instance using the code CLI on an Ubuntu machine. The gateway has been given an automatically generated name, but I'd like to change this name so that it's more consistent with the other services on this machine. How do I do this?

Looking at this GitHub discussion, it's as simple as using code tunnel rename <new gateway name> to change the name of your tunnel to something new. Hopefully, this is useful to those who are disinclined to documentation trawling!

as an addendum, if you get a 400 bad request after running it, try checking if you're using disallowed characters like dots. Hyphens and underscores seem to be ok.
